# Why does this 'for' loop stop randomly in Python

Tags: python

I have a for loop in a section of code I have been working on where for every item in  a list it loops a process of eventually removing one item and goes back around again.

When I run the code it stops at 10 items left in the list out of 30 items at the start.

```
cards_blue = ["b1","b2","b3","b4","b5","b6","b7","b8","b9","b10"]
cards_red = ["r1","r2","r3","r4","r5","r6","r7","r8","r9","r10"]
cards_yellow = ["y1","y2","y3","y4","y5","y6","y7","y8","y9","y10"]
deck = cards_blue + cards_red + cards_yellow
random.shuffle(deck)
for card in deck:
```

Then I have at the end of the card game process:

```
    if not deck:
        if card_score1 > card_score2:
            print("Player 1 is the final winner, they have the most cards")
        elif car_score2 > card_score1:
            print("Player 2 is the final winner, they have the most cards")
        print("Deck is empty")
```

At the end of all 30 loops of the game it will decide the winner using a scoring system but it stops before it can finish.
I am unsure about why this is, could anyone help explain why this happens?

Comment: The code you have posted runs for 30 cards. Can you post the code inside the for loop?

Comment: What is this `removing one item` that you speak of. This may be incompatible with your loop: `for card in deck`.

Comment: problem is in the "(*runs the card game process*)"

Comment: When I say removing one item it means after the loop process the first item in the list is removed,and the code loops for every remaining item until there is none left.

Comment: You shouldn't be removing items from a list while you are iterating over it

Comment: I put "(runs the card game process)" there because there is a lot of code that goes in that loop that I am not sure could be posted without a 'good' answer help link.

Comment: You could loop over a *copy* of the deck: `for card in deck[:]:`

Comment: You are mutating the list while iterating https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: I am just confused about why it works until the last 7 items are left.

Comment: That is explained in the dupe I have linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider switching to a while loop if you will edit the list, for example:

```py
while deck:
    card = deck.pop(0)
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, this solved it.